# How to remove object from v-model array when field in the object has changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-model

I have set up a vue.js file with a checkbox input that will add an object to an array when clicked. But I have another select box input that can change the value of one of the fields in the object, so when I click the checkbox again to unselect that object because the original value and the changed value are different, the v-model on the checkbox just adds another object to the array instead of removing the object that still has 2 fields with the same values in.

How do I get the v-model to remove the object from the array, even if 1 field value has been changed?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="user" :value="{ name: displayName, email: userEmail, level: '' }" />
    <select v-model="user.level">
      <option value="low"> Low </option>
      <option value="middle"> Middle </option>
      <option value="high"> High </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    user: []
  })
}
</script>
```

An example user array containing an object.

```
user: [
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    level: 'low'
  }
]
```

So when I add John to the array I am able to add and remove him. But when I change his level, because level is not a blank string any more, click Johns checkbox again adds his to the users array again instead of removing him.

Is there a way of v-model being able to remove an object from the array depending on the value of one field, e.g. 'name' because that value will not change, instead of matching the whole object to the object already in the users array?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] for example, where are you adding/removing users? Best would be a working demo, but at least provide minimal reproducible code in question.

Answer (score 0):

your `user` is an array, and your select is set to model `user.level`. What this does is putting a property `level` onto the array. What you want is to do that to individual object inside that array.

What you are missing is a `v-for`

```html
<div v-for="_user in user">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="_user" :value="{ name: displayName, email: userEmail, level: '' }" />
    <select v-model="_user.level">
      <option value="low"> Low </option>
      <option value="middle"> Middle </option>
      <option value="high"> High </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

should probably name the array of user `users` though.